# dynamically generated element appears lowly by using opacity and transition? (javascript, css)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my goal is to create a li element by pressing a button. this element should appear slowly. I want to use css and javascript with jquery.

that's what i tried:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add', function(){

    var li = '<li style="transition: all 10s; opacity: 0;"> some content </li>';
    $(li).appendTo("ul");
    $("li").last().css( "opacity", "1" );

});
```

sadly this didn't work. For some reason the delay has no effect on the generated li item. So what do i need to change?

Comment: Please add a working code snippet to work with

Comment: better add a class with all the css on it and just add the class on element instead of straight forward adding css in js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out.. This will solve your problem

http://jsfiddle.net/tirthrajbarot/tfmFx/39/

html

```
<button>Click me</button>


<ul id="myList">
</ul>
```

JS:

```
   $('button').live('click', function() {
    $("#myList").append("<li class='fade'>This is just a test</li>")
        setTimeout(function(){$(".fade").addClass("in");}, 0)
});
```

CSS

```
 .fade.in { opacity:1;}
 .fade {  opacity: 0; -webkit-transition: opacity 0.7s linear; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without css3 transition, but works =)

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
    var $li = $('<li> some content </li>').hide();
    $("ul").append($li.fadeIn());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="add" value="add">
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 ways:

- Using `.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )` jQuery method [description](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp); [example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_animation1)
- Using css animation [description](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp); [example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation1)
- Setting timeout before using `.css`